# Functions with four peaks

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I'm enrolled in a machine learning course and I need to apply some optimization algorithms on some functions with at least $4$ peaks and using single integer variable $x$.

I tried some polynomial functions of $4$th degree but I couldn't make more than $2$ peaks like this function:

$$y=-4x^4 + 1000x^3 - 20x^2 + 4x - 10$$

Any idea what sort of functions could be? I need $3$ functions with at least $4$ peaks where there is only $1$ global peak

Comment: Use polynomials of degree 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can make a function with $4$ peaks using a polynomial of degree more than $4$.  Any polynomial of the form $$p(x) = - \prod_{i=1}^8 (x - r_i)$$ for real distinct $r_i$ is going to work, so long as their isn't reflectional symmetry between the $r_i$ (preventing a strict global max). If the roots are real, the degree corresponds to the number of times it passes through the x-axis.  Then it goes through the x-axis, peaks, drops down past the x-axis to a valley, back through the x-axis to a peak, down to a valley, etc.

All in all we count $8$ intersections with the x-axis.

This polynomial will have exactly $4$ peaks and $3$ valleys because, being of degree $8$, it's derivative can have at most $7$ real zeroes.

Comment: Thank you. That was beautiful.  I tried it on desmos and by little tweaking I managed to get some nice functions as I needed